# Want to Create buttons inside a UITableViewCell and display as seat layout

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am developing an Theatre Ticket booking iOS Application. In that I want to display a seat layout so that an user can select the number of seats he wants. so i planned to display it in row wise and column wise inside a table view. Is that suggested? Or any other solutions are there?? Here is my code for displaying the buttons inside a UIScroll view. How can I move further. Also I need to handle click events for those buttons and get information and handle later. I need some ideas for that too... Please suggest me some samples.

```
- (Void) someMethod {
    int x = 20, y = 15, rows = [rowsArr count];

    for (int i = 0; i < [rowsArr count]; i++) {

        NSDictionary * rowsDict = [rowsArr objectAtIndex:i];
        NSArray * seatsarr = [rowsDict valueForKey:@"Seats"];

        if (![[rowsDict valueForKey:@"RowDescription"] isEqualToString:@"Way"])


            [self chapterCreationwithtitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [rowsDict valueForKey:@"RowDescription"]]
                            withChapterTag:tag + i
                                 andXvalue:x andYvalue:y];
        y = y + thumb_incrementY;

        if (i == rows) { // (main_scroll.frame.size.width-thumb_incrementX))
            x = x + thumb_incrementY;
            x = 40;
            index1++;
            rows = (rows + [rowsArr count]);
        }



        strSeatDes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        int seats = [seatsarr count];
        for (int j = 1; j <= [seatsarr count]; j++) {
            NSLog(@"index %d", index2);
            NSDictionary * seatsDict = (NSDictionary *)[seatsarr objectAtIndex:j - 1];
            [strSeatDes addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [seatsDict valueForKey:@"SeatDescription"]]];

            if (![[seatsDict valueForKey:@"isPassage"] boolValue])
                [self seatsCreationwithtitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [seatsDict valueForKey:@"SeatDescription"]] withSeatsTag:tag2 + j andXvalue:xx andYvalue:yy];
            xx = xx + thumb_incrementX;
            NSLog(@"tag seat:%d", tag2 + j);
            if (j == seats) {
                yy = yy + thumb_incrementY;
                xx = 80;
                index2++;
                tag2 = tag2 + 100;
                seats = (seats + [seatsarr count]);
            }
        }
        NSLog(@"%d", [strSeatDes count]);

        main_scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(([seatsarr count] + 2) * thumb_incrementX + 110, ([rowsArr count] + 2) * thumb_incrementY);
    }
} /* someMethod */

- (void) chapterCreationwithtitle:(NSString *)title withChapterTag:(NSInteger)tags andXvalue:(NSInteger)x andYvalue:(NSInteger)y {

    chapter_button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    chapter_button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, button_width, button_height);
    chapter_button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
    [chapter_button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [chapter_button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    chapter_button.titleLabel.font  = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
    [chapter_button setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
    [chapter_button setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];
    [chapter_button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    [chapter_button setTag:tags];
    //  [chapter_button addTarget:self action:NSSelectorFromString(@"getAction:") forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.main_scroll addSubview:chapter_button];
}

- (void) seatsCreationwithtitle:(NSString *)title withSeatsTag:(NSInteger)tags andXvalue:(NSInteger)x andYvalue:(NSInteger)y {

    seats_button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    seats_button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, button_width, button_height);
    seats_button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
    [seats_button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [seats_button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    seats_button.titleLabel.font  = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
    [seats_button setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
    [seats_button setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];
    [seats_button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.09375 green:0.09765 blue:0.02734 alpha:0.4]];
    [seats_button setTag:tags];
    [seats_button addTarget:self action:NSSelectorFromString(@"getAction:") forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    // main_scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(x+50, y+50);
    [self.main_scroll addSubview:seats_button];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want users to view the seats as they are laid out in the theatre, and to highlight one or more seats in order to book them.

If this was me, I would not use a `UITableView`. I think in iOS tables are actually more for displaying lists than two dimensional information. However, it can be done - basically you make your own custom cell which is split in to columns. Some code here https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView might be useful.

Personally I would think about maybe just having a grid of `UIButton` controls instead. It depends on how many seats there are, and if they fit on to a single screen.